# Can't run app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I opened my app (created on Eclipse) on android studio after generating gradle file, but it gives me the following errors.

[image]

I done clean and rebuild, but still the same. How to solve it?

Comment: See if you have dependencies `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.+'` in gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove play.png image file or remake play.png file. i think that's the problem.

Comment: yes, you are right. I deleted this image and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this generally happen when a JPG or equivalent image is renamed to PNG and added to Android Studio. Try recreating and adding these images.